# use request in form class in django

Tags: python, django

I have a form just like this:

```py
class addMeal(forms.Form):  
      
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=40,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'نام وعده'}))
    foods = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Food.objects.filter(user=1),widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
            model = Meals
```

i need write a queryset to get user id with request(see the `queryset=Food.objects.filter(user=1)` )
what should i do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override the constructor:

```
class MealForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'نام وعده'})
    )
    foods = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Food.objects.none(),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs, user=None):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields['foods'].queryset = Food.objects.filter(user=user)

    class Meta:
            model = Meals
```

In this case you should also inherit from `ModelForm` instead of `Form`. In the view, you then pass the user to the view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    MealForm(user=request.user)
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).